# angular/angularfire 17 , sw/ssr , when ng build get error : Module 'undici' and @grpc/grpc-js/ used by ... is not ESM

Tags: angular, firebase, server-side-rendering, angularfire, angular-pwa

new project

angular 17 , angularfire 17 , sw/ssr.

when ng build get error/WARNING

```
▲ [WARNING] Module 'undici' used by 'node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index.js' is not ESM

  CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
  For more information see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies


▲ [WARNING] Module '@grpc/grpc-js' used by 'node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.mjs' is not ESM

  CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
  For more information see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies


▲ [WARNING] Module '@grpc/proto-loader' used by 'node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.mjs' is not ESM

  CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
  For more information see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies


▲ [WARNING] Module 'faye-websocket' used by 'node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js' is not ESM

  CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
  For more information see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies


▲ [WARNING] Module 'undici' used by 'node_modules/@firebase/functions/dist/esm-node/index.node.esm.js' is not ESM

  CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
  For more information see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

▲ [WARNING] Module 'undici' used by 'node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js' is not ESM

  CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
  For more information see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

```
**# **Angular: 17.0.8
# animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
# platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
# router, service-worker, ssr****

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1700.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.0.8
@angular-devkit/core            17.0.8
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.0.8
@schematics/angular             17.0.8
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.2.2


http-server version: 14.1.1

http-server settings:
CORS: **disabled**
Cache: -1 seconds
Connection Timeout: 120 seconds
Directory Listings: visible
AutoIndex: visible
Serve GZIP Files: **false**
Serve Brotli Files: **false**
Default File Extension: **none**
```

ng build need to

sucsses

and

create dist folder

Comment: you have not shared the error! warnings do not make the build to fail!

Comment: You are right in that there is no error, only a warning, although there is only a warning in the build procedure "finishing" without creating a dist folder

From what I understand this happens when you create a new project with ssr and install angularfire 17
When you run ng build
You will receive this warning and this ends the process without creating the dist folder.